# Monodevelop cannot connect to debugger

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, monodevelop

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 (with Gnome 3.10.1) and MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2.

Before switching to GDM and Gnome 3 MonoDevelop worked just fine, but after switching I get this popup: "Could not connect to debugger" (as the picture shows, first the "Waiting.." popup pops up, then the could not connect (all this happens instantly)).

I am aware you can use the internal console (Project -> Options -> General) but it does not do it for me. I want the Gnome-terminal as I'm used to.

Does anyone know a fix to this? (Yes, I've tried reinstalling (including apt-get purge and removing the settings in ~/home)

[image]

Answer (score 12):

this little trick , works on my debian 8 (Cinnamon)

1. Go to Solution Options via Project > ProjectName Options
2. Under Run > General Section disable the Run on external Console for both Debug and Release Configuration

---

now it should work for you.

Comment: There is no such option.

Comment: I don't see "General" under "Run". I only see "Configurations".

Comment: you dont see that option because this answer belongs to 2016 :))

Answer (score 11):

This is due to a recent gnome-terminal change. Recent gnome-terminal no longer accepts the --disable-factory argument.

Install the xterm package, then in a gnome-terminal session do the following:

```
$ unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
$ monodevelop
```

This will cause monodevelop to use xterm as its external terminal and all should be well.

Comment: For KDE, it's `KDE_SESSION_VERSION`, for Mate - `MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID`

Comment: ......but this fix doesn't work with an XFCE desktop :-(

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs on Xubuntu 18.04 the workaround mentioned on https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/9xa7b8/monodevelop_could_not_connect_to_the_debugger/ works: `export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=1 && monodevelop`

Answer (score 2):

```
su
cd /opt/monodevelop && nano monodevelop.sh
```

in `monodevelop.sh`, write:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset -v GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
cd /usr/bin && ./monodevelop-opt    #or monodevelop if exist
```

save the file and:

```
chmod +x monodevelop.sh
ln -s /opt/monodevelop/monodevelop.sh /usr/local/bin/monodevelop
cd /usr/share/applications/ && nano monodevelop-opt.desktop #or monodevelop.desktop if exist
```

in the file, set or modify lines: `Exec=` and `TryExec=` to:

```
Exec=monodevelop %F
TryExec=monodevelop
```

Save the file.

Comment: The variable is `XDG_SESSION_ID` on xfce, but unsetting it simply changed the error message to `Debugger operation failed` :-/

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here that Mono is trying to open `mcs` to execute the console program. But since the `mcs` is not installed in the system, it keeps giving that error message. You just need to install `mcs` and that's all.

Open up the terminal and type this command: `sudo apt-get install mono-mcs`

This will probably solve the issue.

Comment: Not true. `mcs` is installed on my system and it still isn't working.